# How to fix dialogflow authentication issue

Tags: java, http, dialogflow-es, gcloud, restful-authentication

I have a dialogflow project that I'm trying to access from Java with a rest call. 
It is giving me an authentication issue.
I have followed all online instructions (and many forum suggestions) to no avail.

I have tried generating the key json, as per the instructions here:

https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v2-auth-setup

and setting my environment variable as described, but nothing seems to work.
I have checked my projectID, and am running off the same machine with the environment variable, and have double, triple and quadruple checked it's name and location, but I still get the following error:

```
java.net.HttpRetryException: cannot retry due to server authentication, in streaming mode
```

Here is my code (though it's a REST call, so I don't know if it's so relevant):

```java
String url = https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/MYPROJECT/agent/sessions/SESSION_NUM:detectIntent
URL url = new URL(full_url);
String inText = "Hello World";
String outText = "";
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
try {
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");

    // set body of http post
    Map<String,String> arguments = new HashMap<>();
    JSONObject inTextJsn = new JSONObject();
    inTextJsn.append("text",inText);
    inTextJsn.append("languageCode","en");
    JSONObject fieldJsn = new JSONObject();
    fieldJsn.append("text", inTextJsn);
    arguments.put("queryInput", fieldJsn.toString());
    StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner("&");
    for(Map.Entry<String,String> entry : arguments.entrySet())
        sj.add(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8") + "="
                + URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));

    // post http post as bytes
    byte[] bytes_out = sj.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    con.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(bytes_out.length);
    con.connect();
    try (OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream()) {
        os.write(bytes_out);
    }
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(),
            "UTF-8"));

    // read all lines to a string
    String line;
    String response = "";
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        response += line;
    }


    JSONObject responseJsn = new JSONObject(response);
    outText = responseJsn.get("fulfillmentText").toString();

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println(e);
} finally {
    con.disconnect();
}

return restResponse;
```

The gist of the code is to simply send a message ("Hello World!") to my dialogflow, and get back my agent's response (the code may have bugs - it's a bit hard to test when I can't get passed this authentication issue, so please help with the authentication, not code bugs).

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directions at that page assume you're going to use the `gcloud` program to generate a currently valid bearer token, which is then sent along with the HTTP headers. That page illustrates

Your code doesn't seem to be generating an `Authorization` HTTP header at all, which is why you're getting the error you do.

Since you're using Java, you should look at the [google-auth-library-java library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java), which will give you the tools to generate the token you need to provide in the `Authorization` header.

You may also wish to check out the [google-cloud-java library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java). This contains Java classes to directly perform operations against Dialogflow instead of coding the REST/HTTP calls yourself. (However, it is still at an Alpha level for Dialogflow, so may not be stable or forwards compatible.)